# ffmpeg player in discord.py (python) automatically leave

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot that on certain messages either sends back a message or plays a sound (like a soundboard)

The crucial line of code is:

```
         soundboard_player = voice_client.create_ffmpeg_player("doh.mp3")
         soundboard_player.start()
         await client.send_message(message.channel, "Playing DOH...")
```

This works absolutely fine but i kept trying to add the line 
             `after=voice_client.disconnect()`
I put this inside the `("doh.mp3", * I PUT IT HERE *)` brackets.
I wanted the bot to leave after it was done.

When I run the code with the 'after' statement included, the bot joins and I get the error message:

```
TypeError: disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I know you can use `soundboard_player.is_done()` to check the status of the bot but I couldn't figure out a way to check the status without trapping the code in a loop

By trapping the code in the loop I cant execute a STOP command to stop it playing the song (soundbite) half way through.

Any help with the `after=voice_client.disconnect()` command for the ffmpeg player
or a creative way to periodically check the status without getting trapped in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

run it threadsafe.

I recommend:

`loop = voice_client.loop`

`after=lambda:
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(voice_client.disconnect(), loop)`

you should write it inside a sync function.
good luck.